# Is isolating overlapping contours possible?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a set of images of phone numbers. Unfortunately the image always has parentheses, `(` and `)`, and a dash, `-`, embedded as shown below:

[image: business phone]

Mind you, this is just one variation of the overlapping problem. Sometimes the `-` will be overlapping with a `1`, for example.

This is severely limiting my ability to OCR the number accurately. Using `RECT_TREE` doesn't improve performance because `1` and `(` or `3` and `)` are getting contoured as one object.

This seemed like a variant of a previous [issue](https://answers.opencv.org/question/171788/how-to-remove-overlapping-contours/) which uses [`groupRectangles()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d54/group__objdetect.html#ga1592d68e4c32a13aa50ed73dbecd6d22) but I am not finding any improvements. I'm wondering if anyone could direct me to where I might be able to solve this or any relevant SO questions.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like the parentheses and dash are likely to be in the same location every time. And if you're lucky, the numbers are a monospace font. If so, you could construct 30 templates and 10 replacements and brute force replace overlapped numbers with non-overlapped numbers. That's one idea. And the most straightforward Another idea is to create very precise bitmaps of the parentheses and dash. Then somehow devise a smart algorithm that can replace those unwanted character pixels with background color.

Answer (score 0):

I would try template matching the parenthesis and hyphens. That would help you identify the where the items of interest are in the image. The first step would be to crop out an image of just a parenthesis and a picture of a hyphen. If this works, then you could determine what the best way to "mask" out the image is with the results. The opencv implementation of template matching returns a set of points representing a bounding box of the object of interest.
(https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html)